# python3 - How to overcome max url limit with python requests

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, web.py

I have two python apps running on separate ports using web.py. I am trying to send JSON strings in the range of 30,000-40,000 characters long from one app to another. The JSON contains all the information necessary to generate a powerpoint report. I tried enabling this communication using requests as such:

```
import requests
template = <long JSON string>     
url = 'http://0.0.0.0:6060/api/getPpt?template={}'.format(template)
resp= requests.get(url).text
```

I notice that on the receiving end the json has been truncated to 803 characters long and so when it decodes the JSON I get:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 780 (char 779)
```

I assume this has to with a limitation on how long a URL request can be, from either web.py or requests or this is a standardised thing. Is there a way around this or do I need to find another way of enabling communication between these two python apps. If sending such long JSONs via http isn't possible could you please suggest alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a Python requests limitation. The maximum URL length is something servers enforce.

Comment: You should be using POST, not GET, for data that large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not put that much data into a URL. Most browsers limit the total length of a URL (including the query string) to about 2000 characters, servers to about 8000.

See [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), which quotes the HTTP/1.1 standard, [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1):

> Various ad hoc limitations on request-line length are found in practice. It is RECOMMENDED that all HTTP senders and recipients support, at a minimum, request-line lengths of 8000 octets.

You need to send that much data in the request body instead. Use POST or PUT as the method.

The `requests` library itself does not place any limits on the URL length; it sends the URL to the server without truncating it. It is *your server* that has truncated it here, instead of giving you a [414 URI Too Long](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/414) status code.